# How to write an XSLT function that requires looping through a list

Tags: function, xslt

I am trying to write an XSLT function that checks a string defining allowed roles versus a string defining the current roles. Both strings contain roles as a ':' separated list. The problem is that I don't know:

- How to proper define the return value of the function
- How to proper use for-each within a function to dynamically assign a value.

Below is my current attempt (which doensn't work) using SAXON-9.9

```
<xsl:function name="acm:isMemberOf" as="xs:boolean">
    <xsl:param name="allowedRoles" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:param name="userRoles" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:variable name="pattern" select="':'"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($userRoles,$pattern)">
        <xsl:variable name="userRole" select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="contains($allowedRoles,$userRole)">
            <xsl:value-of select="boolean('true')"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:value-of select="boolean('false')"/>
</xsl:function>
```

Comment: In the easiest case you just want/need `<xsl:sequence select="tokenize($userRoles, $pattern) = tokenize($allowedRoles, $pattern)"/>` as it returns true if at least one item in the sequence returned by `tokenize($userRoles, $pattern)` is equal to at least one item in the other sequence returned by `tokenize($allowedRoles, $pattern)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to describe your requirements in more detail. Reverse engineering the requirements from code can lead to wrong assumptions.

However, it looks to me as if you're trying to write XSLT as if it were a procedural language like Java, where "for" really is a loop and you can exit from the loop when you find a matching item. That's completely the wrong approach for a functional language like XSLT. `xsl:for-each` is not a loop; it is a mapping expression that applies a function (the body of the instruction) to every selected item.

I suspect that what you are trying to do is:

```
<xsl:function name="acm:isMemberOf" as="xs:boolean">
    <xsl:param name="allowedRoles" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:param name="userRoles" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="some $t in tokenize($userRoles, ':') 
                  satisfies contains($allowedRoles, $t)"/>
</xsl:function>
```

It's also possible that you are using `contains(x, y)` where you should be using `x = y`. It's a surprisingly common mistake (I think people assume they can guess what the function does from its name, which is a dangerous assumption).